# Spring security authentication fails with Custom user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to authenticate with Custom `User` that implements `UserDetails`. Here is my custome `User` class. (This class is also extended by other classes like `Citizen` and `Employee` as well).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean isActive;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDate createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDate updatedAt;

    @Transient
    private Set<GrantedAuthority> authorityList;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorityList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setAuthorityList(Set<GrantedAuthority> authorityList) {
        this.authorityList = authorityList;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = active;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public LocalDate getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDate createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDate getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDate updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }



}
```

Also I have implemented `UserDetailsService` as

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()){
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        user.setAuthorityList(grantedAuthorities);
        return user;// new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

And `WebSecurityConfig` as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration", "/newreport", "/login*", "/signin/**", "/signup/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

}
```

Authentication works find if i return `new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);` inside `UserDetailsServiceImpl`.
But as soon i return `User` class object `user`. Authentication fails.

I am not sure what i am missing here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `UserDetails` implementation always return `false` for the following methods:

```
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

In order to pass the authentication , all the above methods should return true.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now. I shouldn't have missed it.